# Custom UIViewController Scene Transitions in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, transition

I'm trying to come up with a custom scene transitions between two UIView controllers. The only way I do transitions between two controllers at this point is as following:

```
// Transition to ViewController B
func transition(_ sender: AnyObject) {
   NSLog("Transition to scene B")
   self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDrawingControllerB", sender: nil)
}
```

With this transition only scroll from bottom to the top works.

I would like to make transition from first to the second view controller like your are flipping book pages or fading with a delay. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I think you use UIview Animation or use Navigation controller with fade animation

Comment: I don't need to use Navigation controller as I programmatically transition between two scenes or two view controllers. What I'm looking for is to transition from one scene to another using animation like a flipping page in a book. Thanks.